# Why does event listener work on the first call but not subsequent calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap carousel where I hide the "Previous" button on the first slide, and the "Next" button on the last slide, and now I want to de-activate the next button on the second (and eventually all slides with iframe videos) until the iframe video ends.  Everything works fine the first time through, but if you get to the third (last) slide, and then use the previous button to get back to slide #2, the next button no longer activates when the video ends.  I suspect this is a scope issue with the event listener, but just can't figure this one out...

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   .textslide{
    height: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body class="text-center" >
    <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">    
      <div id="M1carousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div id ="slide1" class="item active textslide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item videoslide">
    <iframe class='iframe' id="video1" width="500" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0Bmhjf0rKe8?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div id ="lastslide" class="item textslide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h1>Thank you for watching!</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
        </div>
      <!-- Carousel control buttons -->
  <div class="text-center mt-2">
   <a href="#M1carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" id="prev">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info prev-slide" value="Previous Slide">
   </a>
   <a href="#M1carousel" role="button" data-slide="next" id="next">
    <input type="button" id="nextbtn" class="btn btn-info next-slide" value="Next Slide">
   </a>
  </div>
  <script>   
   $(document).ready(function(){
    // Activate Carousel
    $("#M1carousel").carousel({interval: false, wrap: false});
    if ($("#slide1").hasClass("active")) { // Hide previous button on Slide 1
      $('#prev').hide();
     } else  {
      $('#prev').show();
     }
    $('#M1carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () { // function called when the slide transition has completed 
     document.getElementById('nextbtn').disabled="disabled"; //disable the next button until the video ends 
     if ($("#slide1").hasClass("active")) {  // Hide the previous button on slide 1
      $('#prev').hide();
      $('#next').show();
      document.getElementById('nextbtn').disabled=false;
     } else  if ($("#lastslide").hasClass("active")) {  // Hide the next button on the last slide
      $('#next').hide();
      $('#prev').show();
     } else {  // Show both buttons on every slide other than the first and last:
      $('#next').show();
      $('#prev').show();
     }
    });
    $('#M1carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () { // function called when the slide is about to transtiion 
     if ($(".videoslide").hasClass("active")) { 
      $(".iframe").each(function() {              // Pause any iframe videos
        var src= $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src',src);  
      }); 
     }
    });     
   }); 
   // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
   var tag = document.createElement('script');
   tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
   // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
   //    after the API code downloads.
   var player;
   function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video1', {
    events: {
  //  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
   });
   }
   // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
   function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
   }
   // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
   //    The function indicates that when a video ends playing a video (state=0),
   //    the next button is enabled.
   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) {            
     document.getElementById('nextbtn').disabled=false;  // Why doesn't this work after the first time???
    }
   }
  </script>
      </div>
  </div> <!-- /container -->
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: second frame doesn't work for me

Comment: Try viewing it here:www.fuzzman.net/Parents/test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the src attribute is destroying the YouTube player instance.

I've included a postMessage to the iframe, but you should store and use the actual YouTube "player" instances you create and call `player.pauseVideo()` on them.

jsfiddle demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/pauc7kfs/1/

```
                    $(".iframe").each(function() {              // Pause any iframe videos
                            //var src= $(this).attr('src');
                            //$(this).attr('src',src);  
            this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
            //player.pauseVideo();
                    });
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you for that.  It works!  I will also try to implement your suggestion on storing the player instances.